# WooCommerce Hiding A Certain Category From Being Displayed On Single Product

Tags: plugins, exclude, categories

If I go to

`wp-content/themes/theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`

then I see this code:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Meta
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product;
?>
<div class="product_meta">

    <?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', ' <span class="posted_in">'.__('Category:', GETTEXT_DOMAIN).' ', '.</span>'); ?>

    <?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', ' <span class="tagged_as">'.__('Tags:', GETTEXT_DOMAIN).' ', '.</span>'); ?>

</div>
```

What modifications are required so that it doesn't display the category, having slug, `certain-category-slug` ?

I could have used the following:-

```
get_categories( array( 'exclude' => 'certain-category-slug' ) )
```

but I believe that WooCommerce `$product->get_categories` is different from WordPress API `get_categories` because their arguments are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about [woocommerce: get_categories()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1008) being different from [wordpress: get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), the woocommerce function uses [get_the_term_list()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list), so there is no way to exclude categories, same applies to [get_the_category_list()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list). You can use [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for this, especially take a look at this [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Categories_Assigned_to_a_Post) from the codex page:

> **Display Categories Assigned to a Post**
>
> Display the categories (or terms from other taxonomies) assigned to a
>   post ordered by parent-child category relationship. Similar to the
>   function get_the_category_list() which orders the categories by name.
>   This example must be used inside the loop.

**Code:**

```
$taxonomy = 'category';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
```

This isn't a complete solution, you have to construct a function based on this and use your new function instead of the default inside `meta.php`.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot in finding directions. However, I thought that instead of writing so much code just do a quick dirty hack: `<?php echo str_replace("Category Name","",$product->get_categories( ', ', ' <span class="posted_in">'.__('Category:', GETTEXT_DOMAIN).' ', '.</span>')); ?>`